# alarm toast notification windows metro app

Tags: c#

I try the code bellow to make alarm notification using toast,I need to know how to make repeated every day or for specific day   :

```
 DateTime dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(time.ToString());
                 DateTime dateNow = DateTime.Now;
                 TimeSpan timenow = new TimeSpan(dateNow.Hour, dateNow.Minute, dateNow.Second);
                 double totalSocunds = time.TotalSeconds - timenow.TotalSeconds;
                 int sec = Convert.ToInt32(totalSocunds);
                 if (sec < 0)
                 {
                     sec = sec* -1;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     sec = sec *1;
                 }
                 TimeSpan second = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(totalSocunds);
                 var customAlarmScheduledToast = new                    Windows.UI.Notifications.ScheduledToastNotification(toastDOM,DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(sec));
                 toastNotifier
```

.AddToSchedule(customAlarmScheduledToast);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register a background task, and choose the appropriate scheduling. The background task would be responsible for checking whether it needs to create a notification, and create it if necessary.

Creating background tasks in WinRT: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh977056.aspx